# Windows laptop suddenly started lagging and working excruciatingly slowly

Tags: google-chrome, laptop, performance, windows-11

**My laptop specs:**
Intel i9-9980HK
32 GB RAM
1 TB SSD
Intel UHD Graphics 630/Nvidia RTX 2060
Windows 11

The laptop suddenly started lagging and operating extremely slowly. Even shifting the cursor to a new textbox takes a couple of seconds. The apps that I most frequently use and are lagging are - Chrome, Windows Explorer, Excel. If I use any processing heavy task such as gaming or running a Deep Learning training model, the laptop performs just fine.

The laptop lags under idle conditions with no load. Example of the resource monitor when lagging and under ideal conditions is below:
[image]

I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps.

1. Updated all the drivers
2. Updated Windows
3. Updated BIOS
4. Cleared all temporary files and system and reserved temporary data
5. Ran disk cleanup
6. Checked for viruses or malware

The worst affected application is Google Chrome. I have tried the following without any success:

1. Clear all cache, cookies and browsing data
2. Tried running chrome both with and without hardware acceleration
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling chrome

Application switching and tab switching lag the most.

Any help or suggestion will be very much appreciated. Thanks

---

## UPDATE

I tried the following commands, they executed successfully but issue did not improve

`sfc /scannow`
`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

I dual booted my computer with Ubuntu to check if the problems persisted in a different OS and **they did not**. Ubuntu worked perfectly and responsively. I also tried to boot Windows in safe mode and that too worked smoothly.

So I inferred that the problem is not hardware based and OS based. So I formatted my computer and reinstalled windows. But the problem did not get resolved on. Windows still works slowly and Ubuntu still works fine. I cannot to seem to understand why Windows suddenly started working so slowly.

Comment: Please post the disk's SMART inside your post. If you don't already have such a utility, you may use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) and post a screenshot.

Comment: @harrymc The SMART test ran successfully. The issue does not seem to be hardware based as the laptop is responsive in Ubuntu but not Windows (even after format and clean installation)

Comment: When you reinstalled Windows, did you test the performance **before** installing any other software? Where did you get the Windows version you installed?

Comment: Yes I tested the  performance before installing any other software. It was better but still not up to the mark, whereas after installation the performance is as bad as it was initially. I deleted all the installed software, disabled all programs on startup, the performance is still bad.

I had installed windows from the Microsoft website using the media creation tool

Comment: This conflicts with your saying that everything works well in Safe mode, where only software by Microsoft is allowed. You must have installed some third-party software or driver that causes the slow-down.

Comment: @harrymc Is there an efficient way to troubleshoot this. Because even when all third party softwares are closed and not running, I am still experiencing slow downs. This problem first started occuring around 3 weeks back, no new drivers have been installed since. Even after format only essential drivers have been installed

Comment: I added an answer that might help, but it's not going to be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem doesn't arrive in Safe Mode, this indicates
that some third-party application or driver is responsible for this
weird behavior.
Here is how to find that application.

You may start with the basic Windows application `msconfig`.
Run it, select startup items from the General tab and reboot.
This might tell you more about the class of application or driver
that creates the problem.

A tool that allows more targeted disabling is the free
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

Autoruns shows all the programs configured to run during system bootup or
login in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return them later with
another click.
You may avoid listing Microsoft products by using the menu
*Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*, *Hide Empty Locations* and
*Hide Windows Entries*.

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches and reboot,
drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. This is a difficult and tedious process and after much tinkering it seemed like the ASUS services were causing the problem so I turned them off. Until yesterday the laptop seemed to be much more responsive and worked better. But today again I am experiencing stuttering and lagging. This is happening erratically and without any discernable patterns. Hence it is proving to be very difficult to troubleshoot according to the methodology you proposed

Comment: I rolled back some of the ASUS drivers and shut most of the unnecessary services. MYASUS and ScreenPadXpert latest driver were causing the slowdowns, which is a little absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Boot PC with a pendrive OS see if it is slow, if yes is hardware, if not is OS, then run "dism" and "sfc" to check filesystem. Plus check the SSD.

```
sfc /scannow
```

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

run SSD tool of the manufactureur.

Measure laptop charger or battery to see if it powers correct values.

Comment: I suspect it is the OS or SSD, as you said. If it is OS, I want to try to avoid formatting my computer to fix this. If it is SSD, I guess I do not have any option. But how to I diagnose that. I have already run diagnostics tools that came from the OEM and it states the hardware is fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).